# Java Truth Table Stack - Pop only returning last calculated value?

Tags: java, stack, truthtable

I'm having trouble phrasing my question correctly, so bear with me. It may be better to give an example.

Here's what I get when I run for P&Q&R

```
PQR:
TTT = T
FFF = F
TTF = F
FFT = T
TFF = F
FTT = T
TFT = T
FTF = F
```

It's just looking at R and taking the values from there, P&Q seem to be ignored completely. If I run for P&Q&~R, the values will be reversed, but will remain the same if I run for example ~P&~Q&R.

My code is excessively long at the moment I know, but am working on shortening it to avoid repeating code. For the moment though, I'd just like to fix this problem.

Here's a code snippet that's supposed to evaluate for FTF:

```
    //Evaluate PQR = false, true, false, ftf

    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
    {
        char ch = x.charAt(i);
        char t = 'T';
        char f = 'F';

        if (ch=='R' || ch=='P')
        {
            S7.push(f);
            ftf+=f;  
        }
        if (ch == 'Q')
        {
            S7.push(t);
            ftf+=t;
        }

        else if(ch=='>')
        {
            if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}
            else if (S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}

            ftf+=ch;
        }
        else if(ch=='<')
        {
            if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}
            else if (S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}

            ftf+=ch;
        }
        else if(ch=='&')
        {   
            if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}
            else if (S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}

            ftf+=ch;
        }
        else if(ch=='v')
        {    
            if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'T' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}
            else if(S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}
            else if (S7.peek() == 'F' && S7.prevPeek() == 'F'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}

            ftf+=ch;
        }
        else if(ch=='~')
        {
            if(S7.peek() == 'T'){
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(f);}
            else{
                S7.pop();
                S7.push(t);}

            ftf+=ch;
        }
    }
```

I can post more code if needed or explain the purpose if not clear.

I want to do something like:

```
System.out.println("FTF = " + S7.pop());
```

to get the correct value.

Infix to Postfix method

```
public void postFix(String x)
{

    Operations newList = new Operations();
    output = "";
    for(int i=0; i<x.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = x.charAt(i);

        if(ch =='>' || ch=='<' || ch=='v' || ch=='&' || ch=='~' )
        {

            while(!newList.empty() && (priority(newList.peek()) >= priority(ch)))
            {
                output+=newList.peek();
                newList.pop();
            }
            newList.push(ch);
        }
        else if(ch=='(')
        {
            newList.push(ch);
        }
        else if(ch==')')
        {
            while (!newList.peek().equals('('))
                output+=newList.pop();
            newList.pop();
        }
        else

            output+=ch;

    }

    while(!newList.empty())
    {
        output+=newList.pop();
    }
    System.out.println("THE INFIX = "+x);
    System.out.println("THE POSTFIX = "+output);

}
```

Comment: Most of this code seems to be specifying how to modify the stack for operators, e.g.`&`, but there are none of these in your input. Why do you expect the code to combine things on the stack to be run? Would `P&Q&R` do the right thing?

Comment: Wait... You're using infix notation and expect the operands to be on the stack when you read the operator????

Comment: My fault, I didn't include the Post Fix code, I'll add it to my original post now - though now that I'm looking at it, I'm popping and pushing to a new Operations called newList that I'm not using in the evaluations.

Comment: @AndyTurner The input picks up the symbols. PQR is just a header for the output so you can see what the T and Fs correspond to.